# How to delete blank lines from code in Netbeans with a Macro Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, replace, macros

Is it possible to write replacement macros for NetBeans?

I need to replace "\n\s*(\n)" with "$1". It seems that is not possible with short regex.

So I wonder is it possible to write such macros?

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans macros cannot handle regex. Your regex/replace works for me so I would use replace in files for this operation.

I suggest to use format source feature (ALT + SHIFT + F). It can simply solve your problem for java/javascript/json (and maybe other) source. You can define blank line policy via menu Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Formatting.